# Community can translate questions?

Tags: discussion, community

I was looking at the [editing history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/74437/revisions) for [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74437/how-to-solve-the-error-in-sources-list-when-updating) which used to not be in English. I noticed that [Community](https://askubuntu.com/users/-1/community) translated the question into English.

I thought this was pretty cool, since, as far as I know, Community is just a process. Does it look for non-English posts and then use a translating service to change them?

The description on Community's profile page makes it sound like it doesn't really do a lot, but now I'm wondering what other things it does.

Answer (score 10):

No, nothing automated here. Community edits are one submitted by anonymous people.

The person who did the translation in this case was a moderator from another SE site who didn't want to register an account. It came through into the edit approval queue and I approved it. The result of all that is what you see.

Comment: Oh, too bad. Not as cool as I had hoped.

Comment: See this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104318/since-when-did-the-community-user-become-sentient